# Pandas function with 2 arguments to find threshold

Tags: pandas, function, dataframe

I need to find people with greater or equal to threshold gain =>
dataframe contains column 'capitalGain' with different values 10,20,30,50,1000,5000,10000 ...etc
I try :

## Function:

```
def get_num_people_with_higher_gain(dataframe, threshold_gain) 
    threshold_gain = dataframe["capitalGain"][dataframe["capitalGain"] >= threshold_gain].count()
        return threshold_gain
```

## Call function

```
df = get_num_people_with_higher_gain(dataframe, threshold_gain)
```

But I get the following error message:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-5485c90412c8> in <module>
----> 1 df = get_num_people_with_higher_gain(dataframe, threshold_gain)
      2 threshold = get_num_people_with_higher_gain(dataframe, threshold_gain)

NameError: name 'dataframe' is not defined
```

Since there are 2 arguments in the function (dataframe, threshold_gain), does it mean that both should be somehow defined within the function ?

Thanks

Comment: Given how you define the function, dataframe should be `df` I think, but the function seems incorrectly defined too.

Answer (score 0):

Finally,
Here is the solution

```
def get_num_people_with_higher_gain(dataframe, threshold_gain):
    result = len(dataframe[dataframe["capitalGain"] >= threshold_gain])
    return result
result = get_num_people_with_higher_gain(dataframe,60000)
result
```